# dataUsingEncoding could lead to crash?

Tags: objective-c

when it steps into `NSString dataUsingEncoding` method, crash happens very infrequently.

source code:

`NSData *latin1Data = [appName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

call stack:

```
MACH_Exception Crashed with mach exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Thread 0 name: (null)
0    libobjc.A    objc_object::release() (in libobjc.A.dylib)
1    CoreFoundation    _common_removeAllObjects (in CoreFoundation) 188
2    CoreFoundation    -[__NSArrayM dealloc] (in CoreFoundation) 28

3    libobjc.A    (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib) 704
4    libdispatch    __dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib) 1148
5    libdispatch    __dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib) 124
6    libsystem_pthread    __pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) 1288
7    libobjc.A    _objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) 40
8    Foundation    -[NSConcreteMutableData initWithLength:] (in Foundation) 316
9    Foundation    -[NSString(NSStringOtherEncodings) dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:] (in Foundation)
10  xxxApp    -[ xxxClass xxxMethod]  xxxFile.mm line：300
```

line 300 of xxxFile.mm is:

`NSData *latin1Data = [appName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Edit, copied from comment:

```
295 -(NSString *)userAgentString {
296     NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
297     // Attempt to find a name for this application
298     NSString *appName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
299
300     NSData *latin1Data = [appName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

crashed at line 300 when called function userAgentString.

Comment: what is the value of `appName` ? what is it - string or anything else ?

Comment: NSString *appName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];

Comment: it's working for me. i have copy paste your code and run into my xcode. no crashes.

Comment: `NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];`
`NSData *latin1Data = [appName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` --> same code working for me..

Comment: yes，most of the time it works,but sometimes it crashes.the frequency is about one in a million.I suspect that there are some bugs in this function.

Comment: Are you mixing with C++?  My guess is a premature release of the string. Need to see more context in the file.  It would be worthwhile to set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: 295  -(NSString *)userAgentString {
296      NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
297      // Attempt to find a name for this application
298      NSString *appName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
299
300      NSData *latin1Data = [appName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

crashed at line 300 when called function userAgentString.

Answer (score 0):

You should pull that information from the mailBundle of your application.

```
NSString *buildNumber = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

p.s:
Im surprised a private Class works. Seems you get a nil reference occasionally. 
(Guessing here: Your class has an initialisation as well. If that one didn't finish in time, the runtime doesn't know the bundle the class belongs to?)